# Failing to use map on my own defined data structure

Tags: haskell

I defined my own rose tree and tried to sum its content. All the types match, but it fails to compile for an unknown reason.
That's my piece of code:

```
data Tree a = Tree {element :: a, branch :: [Tree a]} deriving (Show)
sumTree :: (Num a) => Tree a -> a
sumTree x = element(x) + sum.map (sumTree) branch(x)
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Prelude> ::l tree.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tree.hs, interpreted )

tree.hs:3:32: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree a -> t0 a’
                  with actual type ‘[b0]’
    • The function ‘map’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘(Tree b0 -> b0) -> [Tree b0] -> [b0]’ has only two
      In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘(map (sumTree) branch (x))’
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
        ‘(sum (map (sumTree) branch (x)))’
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: Tree a (bound at tree.hs:3:9)
        sumTree :: Tree a -> a (bound at tree.hs:3:1)
  |
3 | sumTree x = element(x) + (sum (map (sumTree) branch(x)))
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

tree.hs:3:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Tree b0]’
                  with actual type ‘Tree a0 -> [Tree a0]’
    • Probable cause: ‘branch’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘branch’
      In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘(map (sumTree) branch (x))’
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
        ‘(sum (map (sumTree) branch (x)))’
  |
3 | sumTree x = element(x) + (sum (map (sumTree) branch(x)))
  |                                              ^^^^^^
```

When clearly

```
Prelude> :t branch
branch :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses in Haskell serve for grouping of code elements only. Haskell function call syntax is not `f(x)`, it is simply `f x`.

You wrote

```
sumTree x = element(x) + sum.map (sumTree) branch(x)
```

which is the same as

```
sumTree x = element x + sum . map sumTree branch x
```

but you meant

```
sumTree x = element x + sum . map sumTree (branch x)
```

The dot is still misplaced, you wanted it to be

```
sumTree x = element x + (sum $ map sumTree (branch x))
```

which is the same as

```
sumTree x = element x + sum (map sumTree (branch x))
```

Comment: I don't think the `.` is necessarily misplaced. OP could well have meant `element x + (sum . map sumTree) (branch x)`. Indeed, to me that's what their whitespacing suggests.

Comment: @amalloy perhaps, though that would seem too advanced an error for someone confused about function call syntax. :) I think confusing `.` with `$` is pretty common.

Comment: About reading those error messages, don't panic, take it slow, read them slowly and the meaning will become clearer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You here applied the `map` on the `branch :: Tree -> Tree a` function, instead of the result of `branch x`. This is due to the fact that te parenthesis are written in the wrong way.

You can implement your function as:

```
sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sumTree x = element x + sum (map sumTree (branch x))
```

Here we thus call `map` with `sumTree` and `(branch x)` as parameters.

Here `branch x` will thus generate the list of branches, we then call `map sumTree` on that list to generate the sum of each subtree, and then we sum these up with `sum`. We then add `element x` to the result.